# Many readers but not when writer available with HashMap java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've crawl through many question regarding this area but my question still remains with me. I'm seeking some elaborate answer as well(If you kind enough?). So i could understand this more clearly and community as well.

This is my question. I have this map.

```
 private static volatile Map<Integer, Type> types;
```

and have static getter as,

```
static Type getType(final int id)
  {
    if (types == null)
    {
      synchronized (CLASSNAME.class)
      {
        if (types == null)
        {
          types = new HashMap<Integer, Type>();
          ....add items to the map 
        }
      }
    }      

    return types.get(id);
  }
```

Problem in this code is first thread can initialize the types so it won't be null anymore. While first thread adding values to map second thread can retrieve data from it. That means corrupted data.

I see that this can be avoid by synchronizing whole method but then multiple readers is not possible. It's an one time construction for that map and there will be no modification. So multiple readers is essential.

Also we can use Collections.synchronizeMap but if i'm correct it also not allowing concurrent readers. I tried but ConcurrentHashMap doesn't solve this either. Maybe due to it's independent partition locking behavior.

Simply what i need is no reading until map created fully and then multiple read should be possible.
Anyone got a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: The way you've written it, multiple reads can happen, just not while the first thread is initializing.  After the initialization is completed, subsequent threads can read simultaneously because types will != null.  Your only other option is to not instantiate lazily.  Also, you should assign to the class variable types as the last step in the synchronized block to ensure reader threads don't get the empty map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution to your problem. Use a temporary variable, so that the reference `types` is `null` as long as the map is not completely populated. If you change the code in that way, it is thread-safe and quite efficient.

```
static Type getType(final int id) {
    if (types == null) {
        synchronized (CLASSNAME.class) {
            if (types == null) {
                HashMap<Integer, Type> temp = new HashMap<>();
                // populate temp
                types = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return types.get(id);
}
```

Thread-safe, lazy and efficient initialization is a frequently required feature. Unfortunately, it's not directly supported by Java, neither by the programming language nor by the standard library. Instead, there are different patterns, and your implementation is known as [Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

---

*A short excursion to C++:* C++11 has support for lazy, thread-safe initialization both in the language and in the library. If there is only one global type mapping, you can write the following in C++:

```
auto populated_map()
{
    std::map<int, type> result;
    // ... populate map
    return result;
}

auto get_type(int id) -> const type&
{
    static const std::map<int, type> map = populated_map();
    return map.find(id)->second;
}
```

If you need lazy initialization per object, you can use the library support around `std::once_flag` and `std::call_once`:

```
class types
{
private:
    std::once_flag _flag;
    std::map<int, type> _map;
public:
    auto get_type(int id) -> const type&
    {
        std::call_once(_flag, [this] { _map = populated_map(); });
        return _map.find(id)->second;
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow that's the KISS right?. Seems working well with my requirement though not much about SYNCHRONIZATION :). Looking forward to accept this but is there any java synchronization solution? just for curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) pattern.  There are specific implementations available in Java 8 but if you aren't adopting that soon, look at Guava's [MapMaker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html), specifically:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Map<Integer, Type> types = new MapMaker()
          .makeComputingMap(new Function<Integer, Type>() {
                    public Graph apply(Type key) {
                           return loadForType(key);
                    }
           });
```

In this case, no one thread will be populating this map (it may be that a single thread does).  The idea is, when a thread enters it will check to see if a value for any `Integer` is available.  If not it will run the function **once**, if it is, it will return it while not blocking